# GNOME-TERMINAL messed up

Tags: terminal, gnome-terminal

If I ssh to a machine and:

```
man df
```

I see this:

[image]

I'm using GNOME-terminal/Ubuntu 10.04 LTS.

So somehow the terminal is messed up, when I want to see the ex.: man pages..

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you checked the color palette settings for your gnome-terminal profile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's failing to show underlined and bold text.  This is sometimes related to the color scheme in use, as it's inherited from the system theme by default.  In gnome-terminal, go to `Edit -> Profile Preferences -> Colors`.  Uncheck "Use colors from system theme" and pick one of the built-in schemes instead.  Works for me!™

Answer (score 4):

Most probably the terminfo/termcap entry for $TERM on the remote system doesn't match the capabilities of your gnome terminal.

Try setting $TERM to something closer to gnome-terminal, maybe some variations of "xterm", or you could always revert to "vt100".